# How to have 2 method with same sign to delete resource of REST service

Tags: c#, rest, http-delete

I have a REST service and I should have two delete methods. Each method expects just one ID.

The first method delete A LOT OF elements:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteNPs(int countryId)
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

The second method delete just ONE element:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteNP(int npId)
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

As you can see the sign is the same, but the effect is totally different. I had thought to create the second method with two parameters, like this:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteNPs(int countryId, int npId)
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

But this is a really bad work-around... and neither I do have the country id in the second case. How do I have to manage the following situation with the REST paradigm?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use different path for each method?

Comment: You mean I should have two different routes for each method? Is this the correct approach of a REST service?

Comment: @Ciccio Please, don't let "correct approaches" overcome your sense of "correct implementation".

Comment: you are right.. but if I have time to spend, I prefer doing the things in the correct way... and not in just a "working" way

Comment: @Ciccio - just remember that REST is just a term and its implementation varies depending on your needs. How your API is structured depends mostly on your domain, not REST determinants only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO if you really rely on some REST standards, you have something wrong with your design.

Normally you'd have following methods:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteNPs()
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}

[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteNP(int npId)
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

If you would like to introduce a parameter, you should introduce another method:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteNPsByCountryId(int countryId)
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

and attach e.g. following routes:

- `DELETE /api/np`
- `DELETE /api/np/1`
- `DELETE /api/np/country/1`

in other case you're making your API ambiguous.

Comment: @Ciccio - Somehow - yes. You can create a subcontroller for this kind of action, but at the end you still need to create a child route to handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are worried that somebody calls "the" wrong method?!

If so, I think the *only* reasonable answer would be: rename those two methods!

Like

```
DeleteNPsForCountry(country)
```

and

```
DeleteNPsById(np)
```

If two things behave differently simply avoid giving them same name in the first place! **Especially** when there is **no** other mean of protection - your current methods have the very same name and even both take an *int*. So - start there; instead of looking into workarounds!

And then of course, to the client you would **also** present them using different paths!

Comment: Sorry I was srong with the name of second method... Of course, the two method have different name (with the same sign), otherwise my program neither would be compile... 
Then, this is a REST service, so I am not calling methods by name but the Http verbs is the discriminating factor

Comment: But still some level is mapping requests incoming URLs to actual methods, right?!

Comment: I am not sure I understood you... I think the mapping is done just on http verbs...

Comment: A rest service still works on some URL. Some HTTP client connects to some URL, and that URL (together with the action of course) drives which code should be executed.